# Reduced Ad Privilege is pointless

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, advertising, privileges-page

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads

There are no ads on Meta. At least I don't see any, and I don't use AdBlock. So, I don't see point of this privilege.

Comment: There are ads on the big three (SO, SF, and SU). Which site are you looking at?

Comment: @mmyers, the link is to MSO's privileges page, so I'd guess MSO.

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting? We should see more ads? No thanks.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Gp6zo.png
Weird...

Comment: @Glitch you're right: Meta doesn't have ads. You have a point with this. Although it's a minor glitch really, the privilege is probably in the core engine somehow and the team didn't think it important enough to remove here. I agree with that

Comment: @GlitchMr: I was wondering who was the other Opera user around here ;o) Cheers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the link you start off with, I'm guessing you're talking about Meta Stack Overflow. And you're right, Meta Stack Overflow has no ads, for anyone. (Because who the heck would pay to advertise here, anyways? The Waffle House Abandoned Unicorn Sanctuary?) In fact, back in the day, the "reduced ads" rep was set to 1 here, even though it was 200 on all the other sites. Since it's impossible to go below 1 rep, that meant there were no ads for anyone.

However, the MSO privileges page was eventually turned into the template page from which all other SE site privilege pages derive. As a result, it has to say that ads are reduced at 200, because that's what's true on every other site. I suppose the devs could work around this, but I would imagine that nobody noticed until you, and that they'll consider it a very low priority even now that you have noticed.

Comment: Actually [SE sites don't have reduce ads at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89988/reduced-ad-privilege-is-pointless#90011), but for some reason Meta does like the trilogy.

Comment: Oh, weird! Based on Hendrik's comment to your post, I'm guessing this is an artifact of "original SE, AKA trilogy" vs. "new SE" development.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be working for me - the real estate taken up by the ads is several lines' worth of text.

Here's a screenshot without this privilege:[image: Not logged in]

And here's one with it:[image: Logged in]

Note that in Firefox's NoScript, I needed to "temporarily allow all this page", *twice*, before the ads started showing up - apparently the scripts that insert ads are dynamically inserted by other scripts, which are in turn inserted by the main site scripts. Quite complex IMHO, but at least they degrade gracefully (with JS disabled, I saw blank spaces where the ads are supposed to appear):

no JS at all:
[image: JS disabled]

after "temporarily allow all", round 1:
[image]

Comment: What's are all those funny words in the toolbar of your browser? :P

Comment: @Jon's Evil Twin: Huh? Oh, *that*. It's [Web Developer Toolbar for FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/); the locale is `cs_CZ`, IIRC.

Comment: Firefox WDT FTW.

Comment: He is talking about Meta though.

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account: Oh. Well, *you* go and tell the monkeys that all their screen-grabbing efforts have been in vain.

Comment: I'd rather  not. Those monkeys pour their heart and soul into what they do - they can be pretty picky if their efforts aren't honoured.

Comment: I was joking about your non-English browser, that's all.

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account: Exactly. I'm in no mood to give them this news, especially given their numbers.

Comment: @Jon's Evil Twin: Ze non-english browsér, eet iz not funny matter, no? Iz vërrry serious, yes? ;o)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you seem to be right.  At first I just thought it was because all sites have this.  But, that doesn't appear to be true:

**[meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges)**:

[image]

This is the same as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), [Super User](https://superuser.com/privileges), and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/privileges).

But Programmers and several other SE sites that I checked have *no* **reduce ads** privilege.

**[programmers.stackexchange.com/privileges](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges)**:

[image]

So, it appears that it's **not** correct that meta.stackoverflow.com must have them because all SE sites have them — since non-trilogy sites somehow have this privilege turned off.

Comment: [In the faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) it still says "**200** Reduced advertising" - strange.