# Can not see advertisement in Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, meta, advertising

I can see advertisements in Stack Overflow. But I can not see any advertisement in Meta Stack Overflow. As per [FAQ for Reduced advertising](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads) I need 200 reputation for that. But I have less than 200 reputation. But I can not see advertisements here.

Comment: And that's a problem? Or are you saying there is the space, but the advertisement doesn't load?

Comment: No problem but why can't I see ads when I don't have it's Privileges.

Comment: Well, I just "fixed" the privilege page. (read its end now :))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "reduced ads" privilege on Meta Stack Overflow requires one rep point. In other words, there are no ads on Meta.

Admittedly, the privileges page here [says that you need 200 rep for reduced ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads). That's because it's true for the other sites on the network, and the MSO privileges page is a wiki that gets copied to every site.

In other words, there is no bug, it's just bad documentation that's caused by the way the privileges page is set up.

Comment: So because of MSO page is a wiki, we can not remove privileges info about reduced ads on MSO?

Comment: Tried fixing the "bad documentation" please take a look.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I thought about doing that myself, but I decided that leaving that information out was better for non-meta sites. Of course there's no definite right answer here, so I'm not going to roll your change back or anything.

Comment: Tim Stone pointed out to me in chat that I wrote [another answer a while ago that's very similar to this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89988/reduced-ad-privilege-is-pointless).

Answer (score 2):

There are no ads on Meta.SO, like there are no ads on all SE 2.0 sites.

The only sites with ads are SO, SF and SU.